# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm still learning how to do stuffs in a canvas like this one. Rendering a rectangle object in a y coordinates.

```
function initCanvas(){
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var cW = ctx.canvas.width, cH = ctx.canvas.height;
var y = 0, x = 0;

function rectObj(){
    this.x = 0, this.y = 0;
    this.render = function(ctx, lx, ly, lw, lh, clr){
        ctx.fillStyle = clr;
        ctx.fillRect(lx, ly, lw, lh);
    }
}

var a = rectObj();

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, cW, cH);
    a.render(ctx, 0, a.y, 50, 50, "blue");
    a.y++;
}
var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 30);
```

`}window.addEventListener('load', function(event){
    initCanvas();
});`

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function with `new` operator:

```
var a = new rectObj();
```

Comment: I tried rendering an oop image. But it cannot be rendered though I used the same format of code..

function landObj(){
  var land = new Image();
  land.src = "land.png";
  this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = 0, this.h = 0;
  this.render = function(ctx, lx, ly, lw, lh){
   ctx.drawImage(land, x, y, w, h);
  }
 }
 
 
 var land1 = new landObj();
 
 function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, cW, cH);
  land1.render(ctx, 0, a.y, 50, 50);
  land1.y++;
 }